# Writing a Python function to check if a string is a pangram or not

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on the Quick Brown Fox Pangram problem, and so far I was able to identify and print out if an input string was a pangram using a function definition that takes an input as a string, compares it to the alphabet, returns either True or False if it's a pangram or not, and then prints "pangram" if True is returned. The output if False is returned is "missing [missing letters]", but when I run the program, "missing" is printed once for every missing letter, and not all on one line. I tried to use a for loop to check each letter in the string against the letters in the alphabet and the letters that were missing, but when I print them the letters print on their own line, and not in one line.

Code:

```py
def panagram(str):
    import string
    alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
    for char in alphabet:
        if char not in str.lower():
            return False
    return True

str = input()
if (panagram(str) == True):
    print("panagram")
else:
    import string
    alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase
    for char in alphabet:
        if char not in str.lower():
            print("missing", char)
```

The expected output for a non-pangram -
`missing [all missing letters]`

My current output -

```
missing [letter] b
missing [letter] c
missing [letter] d
...
```

Comment: Post code as text here, not links to images.

Comment: Please try to chop up your text into smaller sentences and paragraphs to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Many different ways to achieve this, e.g. you can add each missing letter to the list and return it. Then you can test if the list is empty (i.e. `len(missingChars) == 0`) or not and print desired output.

```
missingChars = []
for char in alphabet:
    if char not in str.lower():
        missingChars.append(char)
return missingChars
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import string

def panagram(text):
    missing = []
    for char in string.ascii_lowercase:
        if char not in text.lower():
            missing.append(char)
    return missing

text = input()
missing = panagram(text)

if not len(missing):
    print("panagram")
else:
    print("missing: ", *missing)
```

I have renamed your input variable from `str` to `text` since it would have shadowed a built in name.

I have also changed your function so that it returns the list of missing characters.

I have then modified your main code to just print the output of the function.

Feel free to comment if you don't understand a snippet of code I used here.